# Can I redirect a page on wordpress to a subdomain

Tags: redirects

I want to redirect mysite/thispage to subdomain.anothersite?

I am offering webhosting on a page on my site but info is on a subdomain. I own both the site and subdomain.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: So you used to have the page of info on your WordPress site, but now that info is on a subdomain?

Comment: A mod_rewrite rule maybe?   A redirection plugin for Wordpress?  Anything causing a 301 redirect should do you.  Should you really be offering web hosting if you need to ask this question here?